# How to make sure a form field remains not required after set to required in is_valid?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form, where I have set `description` as not required.

```
class LeaveApprovalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest

    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea,
        label='Reason',
        required=False
    )

    def is_valid(self):
        '''A description is not required when approving'''
        self.fields['description'].required = False
        if self.data.get('reject', None):
            self.fields['description'].required = True
        return super().is_valid()
```

However when the form is validated and shows the `This field is required.` error. The html has the `required` attribute so if it is not rejected and approved the jquery popup requiring data entry is triggered.

How do I ensure when the formis initialises again it is not required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should not override `is_valid`. The correct method to override is called `clean()`.

Secondly, you should not modify the required status of the fields. Rather, in your `clean()` method, check for the required combination and raise validation errors if necessary.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.data.get('reject') and not self.data.get('description'):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Description is required if data is supplied')
        # or
        self.add_error('description', '....')
```